# Referencing stored queries in Access Database from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am fairly competent at Excel VBA but a newb when it comes to the Access app as well as Access VBA. I am putting together a multi-user application which has an Access database at the backend with an Excel front end (the design is determined by the distributed audience of the application and their familiarity with Excel as well as non-familiarity with Access).

The conceived design involves splitting the Access database with each user having their own front end database that links to the back-end tables. Through an Excel userform interface I am required to populate a combobox with the list of stored queries in the database.  Stored queries may be added or deleted by an administrator which necessitates that the combo-box be dynamically populated only (to the exclusion of all other possible solutions).

Having read up a fair amount of responses on forums, I am aware that this is straightforward to achieve if Access is your host application, but I have yet to come across (what appears to be) a credible solution to achieve this through Excel VBA. I don't have any code to volunteer at this point. Please help!

Comment: Have you connected to your MS Access database from VBA?. Are you able to populate a list box from a database? It's important to have a starting point to suggest from. Here's some sample VBA to get a list of queries that I found when I googled. https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-list-of-tables-or-queries-from-access/

Comment: Hi Nick - thanks for your reply.  Yes, the code (is intended to) reside in an Excel userform on which the combobox/listbox is present (that I wish to populate).  Yes, the Access database is connected to Excel by VBA using a ADODB.connection  If the list of stored queries in the database was static, I would not have a problem at all since I would just have used comboxbox.add method "A", "B" ..."N".  As things stand (to continue the example) the database may have queries A, B, C to start with - that could change to A,C,D and finally land up with queries C,D,E - is why the cmb needs to be dynamic

Comment: The link I posted lets you run some code that returns the querydefs which you then populate the list box with. In particular this line: `For Each Qry In db.QueryDefs`

Comment: Then you just use `AddItem` on the combobox to fill it with `Qry.Name`

Comment: Thanks a million Nick - exactly what the doctor ordered! Appreciate your help very much and have a great day ahead! Cheers

Comment: If you managed to get some complete code - please post as an answer and then you should be able to accept it